# How am I getting users with no user agent string?

Tags: browser, request, header, agent

I've built a web booking system that signs people up for courses.

In order to provide the best web experience I've been logging the user agent.

It's a .Net 6 project. I am using this to get the user agent.

```
string userAgent = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
```

I was under the impression that almost all browsers will return a user agent string and that if it's null then it's likely to be a bot.

However, several of these users have gone on to complete paid bookings successfully so are clearly not bots.

The question is. What browser does not return a user agent string? I am finding 95% of users are on mobile devices. Or, does the above code not work in some circumstances?

Are there incognito browsers that don't sent user agent?